# Why declare variables as static in Objective-c class method?

Tags: objective-c, static, scope, class-method

I don't understand why variables are declared as `static` in Objective-c class methods?

What is the scope of the `static` variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` variables don't get destroyed when their stack frame is popped off the stack (normal variables do, otherwise you'd get epic memory leaks). See them as global variables you can only access locally. They'll stay alive till the entire program terminates.

Example:

```
+ (id)sharedInstance {
  static singletonInstance = nil; // for example
  if (singletonInstance == nil) {
    singletonInstance = [[self alloc] init];
  }
  return singletonInstance;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, the stack frame is not "inside { and }". It is the set of local variables and function arguments, together with the return address and some household locations (e.g. to temporarily store the stack pointer and some registers). It becomes invalid when when one returns from the current function block, either explicitly by calling return or implicitly by simply reaching the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

The scope is at the file level just like in C. And since it is static the variable will remain for the lifetime of the application and all instances of the class will have access to it. Good examples would be to reference a singleton instance, implement a global counter, or some sort of resource lock.